# merge two key values if it is same in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
[
    {
        "a": 'test',
        "b": "10er"
    },
    {
        "a": 'test',
        "b": "yt45"
    },
]
```

if value of "a" is same in both the objects then i want to merge the value of b into single object

```
[
  {
    "a":'test',
    "b":'10er,yt45'
    }
]
```

i have tried getting the duplicates and then tried to merge those with the reamining but no luck.

expectation
if value of "a" is same in both the objects then i want to merge the value of b into single object

```
[
  {
    "a":'test',
    "b":'10er,yt45'
    }
]
```

Comment: why an array as result? what have you tried? please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+objects+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I suggest merging `b` into an array `["10er", "yt45"]` instead of a string. Otherwise merging entries with commas like `{ b: "lorem,ipsum" }` may cause ambiguities.